# How to get SOAP return value using c#

Tags: c#, soap

I have a `SOAP` response as below

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body>
<Login xmlns=\"http://s.com/sch">   
<error/>
<userid>11</userid>
</Login>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am using `XDocument` to parse this `SOAP` . and I am trying to get the value of `userid`

My Code is

```
XDocument xDocc = XDocument.Parse(responseSOAP);
string uid = xDocc.Descendants("userid").First().Value;
```

I am not able to get the value of `11`, it just return me a `NULL`

Comment: How do you set the value in `responseSOAP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
XDocument xDocc = XDocument.Parse(responseSOAP);
XmlReader xr = xDocc.CreateReader();
xr.ReadToFollowing("userid");
string uid = xr.ReadElementString();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var result = from p in xDocc.Descendants() 
             where p.Name.LocalName == "userid" select p.Value;
```